# How can I load an aspx page in another aspx page in a specific <div> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to update a certain part of the page with content from another *.aspx page, thus avoiding having to have just one (very) long page of code.

So: How can I load an aspx page in another aspx page in a specific  tag, without having to reload the entire page.

Comment: More specifics needed.  Are you using an UpdatePanel?  Does the new content have any controls that will be posted back?

Comment: It's going to have controls. I have been trying to use an UpdatePanel in the last hour but can't seem to find a way to load the page with the new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Webforms (and it sounds like you are), you might want to look into User Controls (ascx pages). 
If you are using MVC, consider a Partial View.

Comment: User Controls seems the way to go. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use AJAX.

You can either put an ASP.Net UserControl in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, or (preferably) use `jQuery.load`

Comment: by using jQuery.load, how do you deal with multiple ViewStates?

Comment: @Adrian: You don't.  If you need ViewState, you can't use jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was just thinking you had a solution for an old problem of mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a web control. That way its all inside there and reusable.

Comment: @elvispt - have you used web controls?

Comment: Do mean this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx ? or do you mean Web Server Controls?

Comment: you derive from `WebControl`.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm having problems getting there. Can you provide a link to an example using WebControl in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the content after the initial page has loaded, you can use [jQuery's ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to load up that page and store the result in the div you want. Otherwise, putting your code in a web control and placing that control on the page will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think conceptually you're going about this with the wrong approach. Besides avoiding a very long page of code, what are you trying to accomplish? There are many ways to pull code out of a class, without necessarily touching your display code. Also try ASP.Net web controls, as they allow you to have reusable view objects.

If you're interested in refreshing the page in pieces, look at AJAX.